# Why do all my links get disabled when using send as method on a form?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code in my web aplication. ( Using foundation bootstrap )

```
<form action="checkout" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
    <a role="button" class="btn-blue" href="checkout">Buy</a>
</form>

<script>
$('a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
</script>
```

I'm using this to send the value 1 to my next page, where i do the checkout of the buy.
It works well on this particular link, but all other links on my webpage get disabled.

Any help on this would be helpfull!

Comment: POST are never passed on the query string. those are GET.

Comment: No read the question better.

Comment: Thx for all pointers on this, i know there are related questions to this matther but not any that are spesific, thx to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're targeting every anchor on the page, not just the one in the form, change it to

```
$('form.checkout a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: While this is true, you could at least have answered the man xD

Comment: @MoshMage - I just did answer the man, and I read the question !

Comment: WOW! The question wasn't that one when I first read it; It was something about "passing POST variables on the URL bar"

Comment: @MoshMage - Nope, that's what the title said, the question was still the same, if one bothered to read it all.

Comment: @adeneo true. true. I just went to them edits. My bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can give your form an id:

```
<form action="checkout" method="post" id="checkout">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
    <a role="button" class="btn-blue" href="'checkout">Buy</a>
</form>
```

Then your JS can be:

```
$('#checkout a').click(function(e) { // Note the change in the selector
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#checkout').submit();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the selector be `#checkout a` if you're targeting hyperlinks within the form?